# Autodesk APS OAuth Callback URL Wildcard Not Saving

Tags: oauth, autodesk-forge

For a client of mine I am working on an integration with Autodesk Construction Cloud and Bim360. However, on the Accept environment I am running into an issue saving my wildcard callback URL in my APS app. I created seperate APS apps for the Dev, Test and Accept environments (and will create an app for production too when the code goes to production). Everything worked fine when creating the Dev and Test apps. However, for the Accept app I get an error when saving a wildcard callback URL. When saving a regular URL everything saves correctly.

For example:

- https://example.com/api/v2/autodesk/oauth/* does not save
- https://example.com/api/v2/autodesk/oauth/ does save

The Accept APS app is set up (as far as I can tell) to be exactly the same as Dev and Test. However, the wildcards do work for Dev and Test but not for Accept.

Does anybody happen to have advice about what I could be doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

Some background information;

I am using a wildcard as the app connecting with Autodesk API is multi tenant with dynamic tenants being created, deleted or updated depending on the companies using the software. In the wildcard section of the callback URL I pass along some (temporary) route paramaters used to identify which company and user combination should handle the callback after login or logout.

This all works perfectly on Dev and Test. I expect this will also work perfectly on Accept as long as I can save the wildcard callback URL for my APS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, wildcards are not supported in Callback URLs.

Note that if you need to pass some additional information (such as a tenant ID) around during the OAuth workflow, you can do so using the "state" field. When redirecting the user to the [authorize](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authorize-GET/) URL, you can simply add a `state` query parameter with whatever data you need, and when the user is redirected back to your application, the callback URL will contain the same `state` query parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I find it interesting that the wildcard callback URLs did work for my Dev and Test APS apps. Nevertheless, I do like the idea of using the `state` query paramater as I think this is indeed a better solution in the long run. I seemed to have missed that in the docs. Once again thanks for your help!